# Washer and Dual Basin Plumbing

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, washer

I recently purchased this house and noticed the plumbing for the washing machine and basin in the basement was partially removed and capped. I’ve been trying to research how I can route the plumbing, but I’m a little confused with the current layout of the plumbing.

I have a kitchen sink directly above, and the little hose running next to the hot and cold pipes is from the gas furnace.

The **blue marked pipe** goes from kitchen sink to waste pipe. (Top floor toilet waste pipe)

**Red marked pipe** Does not connect to sink upstairs, but runs down the pipe that ties into the yellow marked, and runs across where the laundry basin would connect to. It also runs across the top, and runs down directly into cement floor of basement.

**Yellow marked pipe** appears to run up (possible vent?), and down through cement floor as well as across running parallel to the floor.

How can I go about connecting the dual basin, and my washing machine to this plumbing, without having to remove all and start new? [image: full view of bottom]

[image: right hand side piping]

[image: left hand side piping]

[image: upper left hand side]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) On the left there are three pipes and a hose.  The two little pipes are hopefully hot and cold.  What's the bigger pipe?  And what's the hose coming from?  2) On the right there's a drain trap.  Where does that go?   A photo of where that goes would be a good addition.  3) Do you have the right electric and if needed gas outlets nearby?  It's an unfinished basement so that won't be a big problem hopefully if you don't.

Comment: Is the drain system all two inch pipe?  I have never seen that and can't give advice but it will help if you clarify that.

Comment: I believe so, yes. This plumbing is original from 1958 so I’m a little confused of the routing lol

Comment: 3 or 4 inch main drains were normal since before 1900.  I don't understand how these 2-inch pipes could carry waste from a toilet or kitchen sink without becoming firmly clogged within weeks.   I hope someone with more experience who has seen this before chimes in.

Comment: Do you have utility sewage?  Or a septic system?  Do you know where the main drain exits from your house?  There should be a clean out there, either just inside or just outside the house or both.

Comment: All sewage goes directly out to the city sewer lines, under the house and to the front yard. I do have a large main drain for both bathrooms. One is a little to the left of this plumbing (where the blue marked pipe runs) and the other main drain is on the other side of the basement where they added a second bathroom on the main level.

Comment: I’m glad I’m not the only one confused by this set up lol

Answer (score 0):

There was a removed laundry sink on the left side and a clothes washer on the right. You should be able to connect the new sink to the pipe on the left (add new p-trap) and extend the pipe on the top of the p-trap on the left for the clothes washer (the existing condensate hose can still drain into this pipe).

I cannot speak as to what the pipe you marked blue is for, as I cannot see enough to decipher its purpose.

The pipe on the right is a drain pipe that comes from above and passes down to below the floor. You can tell it is a drain as they did not use 90° elbows to offset it into the wall above. Before this pipe enters the floor, there is a drain takeoff for a clothes washer. There is also a vent connected to the horizontal section to vent this fixture. This vent continues up to the floor above (here, they used 90° elbows to make the offset). This vent also connects the vent from the leftmost pipe. The leftmost pipe drains a sink with a vent continuing up and offsetting to and connecting to the clothes washer's vent.

In the attached sketch, the green pipes are drains, and the red pipes are vents.

[image]